Remove the footline on a specific slide in beamer from within a theme
I'm trying to create my own beamer theme, which has a custom footline. The problem I'm having that I want to remove the footline on specific slides (mainly the title page, (sub)section page and part page). I may later consider other slides as well, like a custom 'highlight' frame.
Usually you would be able to do this using something like:
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{frame}
   \titlepage
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[customtemplate]

However, I do not want to make it the user's responsibility to change the footer, I want this to be done by the theme itself.
A solution that does somewhat work in the case of the titlepage is this:
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mycustomtemplate}{
  \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
     % Empty footer for the titlepage
  \else
     % Not so empty footer for everything else
  \fi
} 

This still has a few issues:

It assumes the title page to be on the first page. While this is most likely the case, presentations without a title page exists, and so do presentations that do not start the presentation with a title page.
This obviously does not work for part and (sub)section pages, nor does it work for 'custom' pages that do not require the footer.

A solution I came up with was to just create a flag variable like \hasfooter and redefine these commands (for example \sectionpage) to set this flag to false. The flag could be used in a similar if statement as above. Something like this:
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{
   \hasfooterfalse
   \oldtitlepage
   \hasfootertrue
}

The problem here is, it won't work like this and requires a frame around the \oldtitlepage, which again requires the end user to remember to not use a frame around these commands.
In short, how would I remove the footer from within a beamer frame when using a command like \sectionpage or a custom command?

Please don't post code fragments. Always make a small, but compilable test file.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71208283/2777074

That works! With regard to that solution, what exactly does \@nameuse{ps@navigation} do?

Screenshot from the documentation in source2e.pdf: https://i.sstatic.net/xVrzgLoi.png
